# Examples and experiences of text and datamining use of open data?

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, licensing, best-practice

I am currently working on a research project that looks at the barriers and best practices when it comes to text and datamining. 
www.FutureTDM.eu
Do you have any experience with this in relation to open data ? Do you have any insights you wish to share and contribute to the recommendations we are developing for the European Commission please contact me ! Looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: Your question, if interesting, is (too) broad. The best practice would be for you to show you did some research already on the subject and maybe split your research in smaller problems. See here to have a better overview of asking the right question : https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question. You should also take the tour to learn the tips and tricks of SE world :)